# Use Php current (Y-m-d) against sql (Y-m-d) for exact match with if/else

Tags: php

```
Ive checked the leads here and have not found the right solution,

<?php
     $mysqldate = $row['callbackdate'];
     $phpcurrentdate = strtotime( $mysqldate );

          if ( $phpcurrentdate == date("Y-m-d") ) {
               echo $row['last_name'];
           }else{
               echo "Nothing";

}

?>
```

The date field in sql is date and the format is YYYY-mm-dd.  The answer       always being returned is "Nothing".  I know this sort of question has many variations but Ive had no luck finding this type.  Im not looking for a range sort just a simple match is all... and the data $row['callbackdate']is functioning as Ive tested all other connections.

So Id appreciate any help! Thanks,
Les

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Comment: So you are only looking for rows from today? That's what it looks like. Just wanted to confirm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
     $mysqldate = "2017-08-28"; //example
     $phpcurrentdate = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $mysqldate); //put your format 
     $today= new DateTime("now");  

          if ( $phpcurrentdate == $today ) {
               echo 'last_name';
           }else{
               echo "Nothing";

}
```

Comment: If you look, $mysqldate and $phpcurrentdate are always the same.

Comment: When I log in to my site I want to be notified if any dates in my date column match the current days date, is this possible?  Typing in a date seems counter-intuitive.

Comment: Hi yes Im only looking for rows from today.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Ill change that variable.

Comment: Is it possible to store a row$[''] in a variable then convert?

Answer (score 1):

The dates are stored as string in your database. As possible solution to this is formatting both as dateTime for example:

```
$today = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$databaseDate = '2017-08-06 20:50:38'; 

var_dump(new DateTime($today) > new DateTime($databaseDate)) // returns true

var_dump(new DateTime($today) < new DateTime($databaseDate)) // returns false
```

Another way to do this is to make your columns type in the database a DateTime. This way you only have to format the current date as a DateTime and then you can compare them

Comment: It would be nice if $date was renamed $today.